# R assign to an evaluated object

Tags: r, dataframe, eval, assign

I want to be able to change the cell of a dataframe by referring to the object's name, rather than to the object itself, but when I attempt do do so it results in the warning `could not find function "eval<-"`.

I can change a cell of a standard dataframe using the code below:

```
my_object = tibble(x = c("Hello", "Goodbye"), 
                   y = c(1,2))

object[2,1] <- "Bye"
```

But I am having trouble doing the same when using the object's name. I can evaluate the object using its name and extract the relevant cell:

```
object_name = "my_object"
eval(sym(object_name))[2, 1]
```

But I can't assign a new variable to the object (error: `could not find function "eval<-"`):

```
eval(sym(object_name))[2, 1] <- "Bye"
```

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? Storing variable names as strings is kind of an anti-pattern in R. Normally these types of problems are better served using named lists. If you are new to R, I would encourage you to consider more R-like ways of doing things. This means taking a step back and trying to describe what you are really trying to accomplish rather than trying to fix the way you decided to try to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `get()` instead of `eval(sym())`to obtain an object by name. You can also use the `[<-` function to write a value to it without requiring an intermediate copy:

```r
my_object = dplyr::tibble(x = c("Hello", "Goodbye"), 
                   y = c(1,2))

object_name = "my_object"

`[<-`(get(object_name), 2, 1, value ="Bye")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x         y
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Hello     1
#> 2 Bye       2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**1) environments**

**1a)** Subscript the current environment with `object_name`.

```
e <- environment()
e[[object_name]][2, 1] <- "Bye"
```

**1b)** or as one line:

```
with(list(e = environment()), e[[object_name]][2, 1] <- "Bye")
```

**1c)** If my_object is in the global environment, as in the question, it could optionally be written as:

```
.GlobalEnv[[object_name]][2, 1] <- "Bye"
```

**2) assign**  We could use assign like this:

```
assign(object_name, within(get(object_name), x[2] <- "Bye"))
```

**3) without clobbering**

**3a)** If what you really want is to create a new data frame without clobbering the input:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(get(object_name), across(1, ~ replace(., 2, "Bye")))
```

**3b)** or if we knew that the column name was x then:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(get(object_name), x = replace(x, 2, "Bye"))
```

**3c)** or without dplyr

```
within(get(object_name), x[2] <- "Bye")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define your command as a string, parse it as an expression, and then use eval:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0(object_name,"[2,1]<-'Bye'")))

> object
      x y
1 Hello 1
2   Bye 2
```